# Elimnar un elemento de un documento embebido - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Tengo mi coleccion de la siguiente manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que deseo es eliminar un elemento especifico de mi arreglo, por ejemplo deseo eliminar la posicion 0 probe con el siguiente script

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no me funciona, ya que no me elimina nada.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y muestra el código _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminar un elemento por su índice dentro del array no se como se hace, pero si el objeto que tienes para eliminar tiene algún identificador único, puedes hacerlo así:

```
db.getCollection('VOMUserRol_copy').update({
  "sCodeUserRol": "B2C_VISOR_ASESOR_RECLAMOS_MOVILES_2DA_INSTANCIA" //Seleccionas el documento que quieres actualizar
},
{
  $pull: { //Usas el modificador $pull que es para eliminar objetos de un array
    "lUserRolEnt": {
      "sDesEntUse": "description"  //En este caso eliminarías todos los elementos que tengan sDesEntUse = "description" --> Fue la unica propiedad que pude deducir de tu ejemplo
    }
  }
})
```

Te dejo también el ejemplo aqui en el mongo playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/dVwDxvIWcOp